# Loopback multiple one to many relationships

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I've started getting my hands dirty with Loopback and I'm a bit confused with the model relationship declarations.

### Example Model

#### `Person`

- `firstname`
- `lastname`
- `idcountrybirth // references country table`
- `idcountrynationality // references country table again`

*Note that `idcountrybirth` and `idcountrynationality` can reference different counties for each instance of a `Person`*

#### Relationship for the above

I was looking for something along the lines of `hasA` for each of the 2 country fields but this kind of relationship doesn't exist.

What kind of relationships do I need to set on Person for the Countries?

Here's an example model of my current ERD, which I'm trying to rework basing it on Loopback.

[image: screenshot of ERD diagram showing one to many relationships on 2 fields in Person table, related with Country table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `hasOne` relation for each. Don't define `idcountrybirth` and `idcountrynationality` as properties, because they both represent a relation between a `Person` and `Country`.

```
{
  "name": "Person",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "firstname": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastname": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "birthCountry": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Country",
      "foreignKey": "birthCountryId"
    },
    "nationality": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Country",
      "foreignKey": "nationalityCountryId"
    },
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Then, using REST API

```
POST /api/Person
{
  "firstname": "R.",
  "lastname" : "Federer"
}
```

Then, assign him a birth country

```
POST /api/Person/1/birthCountry
{
  "name": "Switzerland"
}
```

And a nationality

```
POST /api/Person/1/nationality
{
  "name": "South Africa"
}
```

Some people have multiple nationalities, so you can use a `hasMany` relationship instead of `hasOne` for the `nationality` relationship ;)